Componente de livewire campo wire:snapshot me pone html en vez de json
tengo un componente en livewire que me está dando muchos errores javascript
livewire.js?id=4ce12f49:1116 Alpine Expression Error: open_form_6 is not defined
livewire.js?id=4ce12f49:1120 Uncaught ReferenceError: open_6 is not defined

Esos son algunos de los errores, pero da muchos mas. Investigando el código html que genera livewire vi que el campo wire:snapshot tiene mucho html cuando debería ser json plano:
<ul wire:snapshot="{&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;p_padre_id&quot;:null,&quot;padre_id&quot;:null,&quot;nombre&quot;:null},&quot;memo&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3QKv7CEjs5bmXQMhbqlh&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;admin.categorias&quot;,&quot;path&quot;:&quot;admin\/categorias&quot;,&quot;method&quot;:&quot;GET&quot;,&quot;children&quot;:[],&quot;scripts&quot;:[],&quot;assets&quot;:[],&quot;errors&quot;:[],&quot;locale&quot;:&quot;es&quot;},&quot;checksum&quot;:&quot;812cd5d99e6a706e3fbd6f1bd746b5398700fecf02db810eb4f5269fe9218e70&quot;}" wire:effects="[]" wire:id="3QKv7CEjs5bmXQMhbqlh">
No entiendo que es
No entiendo porque el campo wire:snapshot tiene html cuando debería ser json plano
Si me pueden ayudar con ese problema, he buscado mucho en google y no encontré nada útil.
Gracias!!!
